# Need SQL data structure information

Tags: dynamics-sl

I am looking a SQL query which will help me to auto generate Voucher and Adjustment Entry records.

I did not able to locate tables for below values.

```
PrePay and Landed Cost
```

Please let me know if any one has idea or any one have data structure diagram of Dynamics SL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find it for Pre-Pay

```
    SELECT APADJUST.adjdrefnbr,
    APADJUST.adjgrefnbr,
    APADJUST.adjamt    
       FROM   APADJUST,
   APDOC WITH (nolock)
       WHERE  
   APADJUST.adjddoctype = APDOC.doctype AND
   APDOC.refnbr = APADJUST.adjdrefnbr AND
   APADJUST.vendid = APDOC.vendid AND
   APADJUST.adjddoctype = 'pp' AND
   APADJUST.s4future11 <> 'v' AND
   APADJUST.adjamt > 0 AND
   APDOC.docbal <> APDOC.origdocamt AND
   APADJUST.vendid = 'E01181' AND
   APADJUST.adjdrefnbr LIKE '%'
       ORDER  BY APADJUST.adjdrefnbr
       OPTION(fast 500)
```